# Vagrant failing: Unable to parse package file

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, apt

I have a vagrant box based on [scotch box](http://box.scotch.io/) with some extra Chef recipes to set up other dependencies.

It's working fine on one Windows 7 machine and an OSX machine, but I have another Windows 7 machine and every time I try `vagrant up` provisioning fails with:

> ==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
>       default: Installing Chef (latest)...
>   The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
>   Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
>
> apt-get update -y -qq
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> stdin: is not a tty
>   E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com
>   _ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index (1)

I tried manually running:

> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
>
> sudo apt-get clean all
>
> sudo apt-get update

They're all using the same Vagrant file/recipes tracked via GIT, I did a clean checkout from a working machine just to be certain there were no differences.

Although even if that worked it wouldn't be much help or explain why it works fine or two machines but not the third even though they're suppose to be the same box image.

I also tried destroying the box and creating it again, and removing the image and downloading it again.

I'm using VirtualBox as my provider and I compared the network settings to a working machine - there doesn't seem to be any significant differences.

I also checked connectivity to us.archive.ubuntu.com from the box and there doesn't seem to be a problem.

I'm basically lost about where to go next with my debugging and what could be wrong?

Comment: try some in this url: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that disabling Windows firewall solved the problem.

I'm not sure exactly why given that curl to us.archive.ubuntu.com worked over SSH, but nonetheless it seemed to work after I disabled Windows firewall.